# setting the maximum segment size in the tcp header

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, struct

I am putting together a port scanner as a learning exercise. My problem is I'm trying to set the maximum segment size option(MSS) in the TCP header. I had a look at tcp.h, but I'm  having trouble figuring out how to set it. I was hoping there would be an option like this:

`tcp_header->mss(32000);`

Something similar to the above was in tcp.h but not in the right struct. Admittedly, I'm still fairly new to reading struct definitions and I couldn't make much sense out of tcp.h so in the end I tried just tacking on the necessary bytes to the end of the TCP header:

```
struct tcphdr *CreateTcpHeader()
{
    struct tcphdr *tcp_header;

    tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)malloc(sizeof(struct tcphdr)+4*sizeof(int));


    tcp_header->source = htons(SRC_PORT);
    tcp_header->dest = htons(DST_PORT);
    tcp_header->seq = htonl(0);             
    tcp_header->ack_seq = htonl(0);         
    tcp_header->res1 = 0;
    tcp_header->doff = (sizeof(struct tcphdr))/4;
    tcp_header->syn = 1;
    tcp_header->window = htons(4096);
    tcp_header->check = 0; /* Will calculate the checksum with pseudo-header later */
    tcp_header->urg_ptr = 0;


    /*memcpy the mss data onto the end of the tcp header. */
    int mssCode = 2;
    int mssLength = 4;
    uint16_t mss = htonl(32000);
    int offset = sizeof(struct tcphdr);
    memcpy( (tcp_header+offset), &mssCode, 1 );
    memcpy( (tcp_header+offset+1), &mssLength, 1 );
    memcpy( (tcp_header+offset+2), &mss, 2);

    return (tcp_header);
}
```

But after I wrote it it was clear that is wasn't a real solution, plus it still doesn't work :P So is there a better way?

Comment: How are you using that header? Are you sending it with libnet?

Comment: I'm just using raw sockets. Although even with the new mss option, my packet is still ignored, despite it being practically identical to nmap's. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Depending on what you are learning - C or networking, you might want to look at http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/

Comment: Wow thanks, I'll check that out looks awesome. Also, my packets are only ignored over the loopback adapter, must be a kernel thing I guess.

Comment: In C, adding a value to a pointer actually give a pointer to n element further, not n bytes further. So your memcpy copy the data to the address tcp_header + (offset * sizeof(*tcp_header)), probably doing corruption somewhere else.

Comment: @MaximeLarocque can you propose an edit to fix the code? You might as well take credit :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `struct tcphdr` in tcp.h defines the mandatory part of the TCP header. (Look at the [TCP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) and you can match the definitions in `struct tcphdr` to your the actual bits to appear in the header.) Structs in C have a constant size, but TCP allows optional data. The header length field (`doff` in the structure) is the total length of the header, including options, so you'll need to add one word to account for the MSS option:

```
tcp_header->doff = (sizeof(struct tcphdr))/4 + 1;
```

Let's define a structure for the MSS option:

```
struct tcp_option_mss {
    uint8_t kind; /* 2 */
    uint8_t len; /* 4 */
    uint16_t mss;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Now you can populate the structure, in the right order:

```
/*memcpy the mss data onto the end of the tcp header. */
struct tcp_option_mss mss;
mss.kind = 2;
mss.len = 4;
mss.mss = htons(32000);
```

Let's go one step further and define a single structure for your packet, to let the compiler 
help us out:

```
struct tcphdr_mss {
    struct tcphdr tcp_header;
    struct tcp_option_mss mss;
};
```

(You may need to add an end-of-option-list option at the end, and nop options to pad the option list to 8 bytes.)

Now we can put all the pieces together:

```
struct tcphdr *CreateTcpHeader()
{
    struct tcphdr_mss *tcp_header;

    tcp_header = malloc(sizeof(struct tcphdr_mss));

    tcp_header->tcp_header.source = htons(SRC_PORT);
    tcp_header->tcp_header.dest = htons(DST_PORT);
    tcp_header->tcp_header.seq = htonl(0);             
    tcp_header->tcp_header.ack_seq = htonl(0);         
    tcp_header->tcp_header.res1 = 0;
    tcp_header->tcp_header.doff = (sizeof(struct tcphdr_mss))/4;
    tcp_header->tcp_header.syn = 1;
    tcp_header->tcp_header.window = htons(4096);
    tcp_header->tcp_header.check = 0; /* Will calculate the checksum with pseudo-header later */
    tcp_header->tcp_header.urg_ptr = 0;

    tcp_header->mss.kind = 2;
    tcp_header->mss.len = 2;
    tcp_header->mss.mss = htons(32000);

    return (tcp_header);
}
```

Comment: ah it all makes sense now. Thanks a bunch.